# How can we check the grants on schemas in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-schema

I would like to know how to check what privileges are granted to specific schema in snowflake? How can we do that in snowflake?

**Tried the following command:**

```
SHOW GRANTS ON SCHEMA <SCHEMA_NAME>;
```

But it failed saying "incorrect syntax or not authorized"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are trying to run this command from another DB which is set for the user.So, if that is so,then use the following expression to check the grants:

```
SHOW GRANTS ON SCHEMA <Database>.<Schema-name>;
```

For eg:
I want to list the grant details for schema XYZ which is under database ABC. But from the worksheet, the database set is def. So, the command would be :

```
SHOW GRANTS ON SCHEMA ABC.XYZ;
```